# Relabelling ticks on Seaborn axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, axis-labels, jointplot

I'm doing a log-log plot with Seaborn; the data is actually derived from a StackOverflow developer survey. I tried using the built-in log scale, but the results didn't make sense, so this simply calculates the logs before plotting.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'company_size_range': {7800: 7.0, 7801: 700.0, 7802: 7.0, 7803: 20000.0, 7805: 200.0, 7806: 20000.0, 7808: 2000.0, 7809: 2000.0, 7810: 7.0, 7811: 200.0, 7812: 50.0, 7813: 20000.0, 7816: 2.0, 7819: 200.0, 7820: 2000.0, 7824: 2.0, 7825: 2.0, 7827: 2.0, 7828: 50.0, 7830: 14.0, 7831: 50.0, 7833: 200.0, 7834: 50.0, 7835: 50.0, 7838: 2.0, 7840: 50.0, 7841: 50.0, 7842: 7000.0, 7843: 20000.0, 7844: 14.0, 7846: 2.0, 7850: 20000.0, 7851: 700.0, 7852: 200.0, 7853: 200.0, 7855: 200.0, 7856: 7.0, 7857: 50.0, 7858: 700.0, 7861: 20000.0, 7863: 20000.0, 7865: 20000.0, 7867: 700.0, 7868: 20000.0, 7870: 50.0, 7871: 2000.0, 7872: 50.0, 7873: 20000.0, 7874: 200.0, 7876: 14.0, 7877: 20000.0, 7879: 50.0, 7880: 50.0 }, 'team_size_range': {7800: 7.0, 7801: 7.0, 7802: 7.0, 7803: 2.0, 7805: 7.0, 7806: 2.0, 7808: 7.0, 7809: 7.0, 7810: 2.0, 7811: 17.0, 7812: 7.0, 7813: 2.0, 7816: 2.0, 7819: 7.0, 7820: 30.0, 7824: 2.0, 7825: 2.0, 7827: 2.0, 7828: 2.0, 7830: 2.0, 7831: 7.0, 7833: 2.0, 7834: 2.0, 7835: 7.0, 7838: 2.0, 7840: 7.0, 7841: 30.0, 7842: 7.0, 7843: 7.0, 7844: 2.0, 7846: 2.0, 7850: 7.0, 7851: 11.0, 7852: 7.0, 7853: 7.0, 7855: 2.0, 7856: 7.0, 7857: 7.0, 7858: 11.0, 7861: 7.0, 7863: 2.0, 7865: 30.0, 7867: 7.0, 7868: 7.0, 7870: 2.0, 7871: 17.0, 7872: 7.0, 7873: 17.0, 7874: 7.0, 7876: 2.0, 7877: 7.0, 7879: 17.0, 7880: 7.0}} )
g=sns.jointplot(x=np.log10(df['company_size_range']+1), 
                y=np.log10(df['team_size_range']+1), kind='kde', color='g')
```

That's fine, but the axes show the log values, not the underlying values. The X-axis, for example, is:

```
-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

So I added this to fix it, using the X position of the labels as the X values:

```
g.ax_joint.set_xticklabels(["{:.0f}".format(10**label.get_position()[0]-1) 
                            for label in g.ax_joint.get_xticklabels()])
```

The trouble is the resulting X-axis labels are nonsense:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0
```

What is going on, and how best to fix it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a [FuncFormatter](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.10-customizing-ticks.html#Fancy-Tick-Formats). The benefit would be that the ticks are always drawn right also after resizing the window.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

def tickformat_pow10(value, tick_number):
    return f'{10**value:,.0f}'

# df = ...
g = sns.jointplot(x=np.log10(df['company_size_range'] + 1),
                  y=np.log10(df['team_size_range'] + 1), kind='kde', color='g')

g.ax_joint.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(tickformat_pow10))
g.ax_joint.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(tickformat_pow10))
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Yo! Elegant! Thank you very much. @JohanC

Comment: And correcting the oddity that the Y axis should be one less:

g.ax_joint.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda value, n: f'{10**value:,.0f}' ))
g.ax_joint.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda value, n: f'{10**value-1:,.0f}' ))

Answer (score 0):

Try the following by first using the `canvas.draw()`. Also, I do not understand why you are subtracting 1

```
g.fig.canvas.draw()

g.ax_joint.set_xticklabels(["{:.0f}".format(10**label.get_position()[0]-1) 
                            for label in g.ax_joint.get_xticklabels()]);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I take it calling canvas.draw() gets it to precalculate the labels, so they can be changed... 

The subtract 1 is standard stats - I added one before taking the log. But it doesn't look right on the axis, as you point out